# How to determine if a FILE_OBJECT represents a normal file or device?

Tags: kernel, driver, wdk, windows-kernel

The MSDN  page on FILE_OBJECT says:

> "Note  The type of object (for example, a file, directory, or volume)
>   that a given file object represents cannot be determined by only
>   examining the contents of the file object structure. For information
>   about how to determine the type of object that a file object
>   represents, see ZwQueryInformationFile."

I have two questions:

1, How to determine the object type through ZwQueryInformationFile?

2, Is DEVICE_TYPE, such as FILE_DEVICE_CD_ROM_FILE_SYSTEM, FILE_DEVICE_DISK_FILE_SYSTEM, FILE_DEVICE_FILE_SYSTEM, reliable to determine?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are implementing minifilter, may be you can use [FltQueryInformationFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff543439%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with `FILE_INFORMATION_BASIC` to get file attributes. Then check for [FILE_ATTRIBUTE_DEVICE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg258117%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) attribute.

Comment: Using `ZwQueryInformationFile` with `FILE_BASIC_INFORMATION` may get the same `FILE_ATTRIBUTE_***` constants.